# meteor - profile editing security

Tags: javascript, security, meteor

So I found [this](http://joshowens.me/the-curious-case-of-the-unknowing-leaky-meteor-security/) article. Is it still actuall or has meanwhile something changed? Should I be worried about user's security? I'm updating user data like so:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {'profile.name': name, 'profile.surname': surname}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `profile` field of `Meteor.users` is subject to debate and might be deprecated in the future (or at least its specific auto-publish behavior). See [this MDG document](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Proposal-for-deprecating-user-profile-3UljX1VayvV). Quote:

> The `profile` field on user documents is very dangerous. New Meteor
>   developers often think it's a good place for all data they put on
>   their user documents, and it's especially convenient because it's
>   automatically published to the client. Unfortunately, profile is a bad
>   place for pretty much anything. In any real app, you will want to
>   validate every bit of data that enters your database.

My advice is to *not* using the `profile` field at all. Instead, add whatever fields you need to `Meteor.users` and publish them the usual way.